# bundle install giving Net::HTTPServerException: 403 "Forbidden"

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, bundler

Guys getting this error any clue, the rubygems.org is up and when i download single gem it does.

```
bundle install
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/........
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
Using rake (0.9.2)

Net::HTTPServerException: 403 "Forbidden"
An error occurred while installing i18n (0.6.1), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install i18n -v '0.6.1'` succeeds before bundling.
```

Any clue on this?

Comment: Have you already tried to follow the bundler's advice and try to run `gem install i18n ect.`? What happens if you try?

Comment: Well i haven't tried, assuming that it should install

Comment: So try it, if the result is different it may help to know. Also may be useful to know something more about your environment, i.e. the version of Ruby, Rubygems, if you are using rvm or rbenv...

Comment: ruby is `1.9.3p392 (2013-02-22 revision 39386) [x86_64-linux]`, gem version `1.8.23` and `bundler version 1.3.5`

Comment: Try changing the gem source at the top of your gemfile from `source 'https://rubygems.org'` to `source 'http://rubygems.org'`

Comment: @Matt, thanks Man.. it worked, my enterprise server was blocking https

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using **http** instead of **https** in your Gemfile should do the trick.

**Use:**

http://rubygems.org

Comment: Thanks , it worked :).. my enterprise server had blocked https :/ silly!